# Laravel:ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function App\Mail

Tags: php, laravel

I failed to make the email queue. Not sure what is wrong as I keep getting the error.

> 'ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function
> App\Mail\TransactionSuccess::__construct()'.

What I'm trying to do is to pass the `$trx` variable when sending emails.

**TestController.php**

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function sendtrx(){
        $trx = Transaction::find('123');

        dispatch(new TrxEmailJob($trx));
    }
}
```

**Jobs/TrxEmailJob.php**

```
class TrxEmailJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $trx;

    public function __construct(Transaction $trx)
    {
        $this->trx = $trx;
        // dd( $this->trx);
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        Mail::to($this->trx['user_email'])->send(new TransactionSuccess());
    }
}
```

**Mail/TransactionSuccess.php**

```
class TransactionSuccess extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $trx;

    public function __construct(Transaction $trx)
    {
        $this->trx = $trx;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('Hey Test')
            ->markdown('emails.transactionsuccess');
    }
}
```

I expect to send an email with details from $trx; however, the job fails based on the table.

> ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function
> App\Mail\TransactionSuccess::__construct(), 0 passed in
> /Users/hey/testcode/app/Jobs/TrxEmailJob.php on line 37 and exactly 1
> expected in /Users/hey/testcode/app/Mail/TransactionSuccess.php:20
> Stack trace:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the handle() method to the following.

```
public function handle()
{
    Mail::to($this->trx['user_email'])
        ->send(new TransactionSuccess($this->trx));
}
```